# Handle refresh page event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to use JavaScript to handle the event of refreshing page?
What I want is get notice if user do one of these behaviours:

- refresh page by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>
- close tab or browser
- enter a new url then press enter on
  browser

to display a warning message?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't want the refresh, you want the onbeforeunload event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx

Sample code from article

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function closeIt()
{
  return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" + 
         "appear before closing the window.";
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Click here to navigate to 
      www.microsoft.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working for the recent version of chrome now :)

Comment: Do not work on Chrome's current version `60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 8):

The closest you could get is the [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Leaving the page';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Leaving the page';
};
```

It is important to note that you need to return a string from this function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need to do anything with `e.returnValue` for IE/FF. You just need to return a string.

Comment: @MattBall - it's referring to IE < 8 and Firefox prior to version 4. see [the docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).