# javascript: Refresh on pre-removed id param URL crash the page

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, reload

**Goal**: Omit the id param from my page AND able to reload the current page.

**Original URL**: www.onecompany.com/dept?id=12345&name=myName

I was able to get the modified url.

**Modified URL**: www.onecompany.com/dept?name=myName

I used this code:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, modifiedUrl);
```

And the page load successfully without the id param.
But when I refresh the page (I want to reload the current page), it did not load

***www.onecompany.com/dept?id=12345&name=myName***

but it load this

***www.onecompany.com/dept?name=myName***

When I attempted

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, originalUrl);
```

The refresh works but one part of my goal is failed, not omit the id param.

I am lost in a circle.

My question: Is it possible to load my page (with id param omitted) AND able to refresh the page (to load the correct page without id param)?

Thanks for any advice !

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're trying to hide the information 'id' for the user. **I would recommend to use cookies** to save the information 'id'.

Otherwise:

```
//Example: 'www.onecompany.com/dept?id=12345&name=myName'

var query = window.location.search;
var oldquery = window.location.search;
query = query.replace(/id=\d+&?/i, '');
console.log(query);
//Out: ?name=myName

window.history.pushState(null, null, query); //then hide the id
```

You have to change the URL back to the original, before the user leaves the website. This will not work.

But if youre willing to do, you could listen for the `window.onbeforeunload` event and change the query back again to `oldquery`. See here: [Handle refresh page event with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950029/handle-refresh-page-event-with-javascript) - But there are a lot of differences between browsers, on how they will process the `window.unbeforeunload` event. They will usually not allow to do that.