# JavaScript: Detect user manual refresh request in web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a **HTML page**, and I would like to send a simple message (or trigger **some action**) when the user intentionally **request updating** (update button on the web browser, pressing F5... or whatever any other manual method that could exist) of the HTML file.
Something like:

```
window.onmanualupdaterequest = alert("You requested update");
```

Or whatever the correct procedure could be.

How could I do this?

Further notes:

- I have tried the `window.onbeforeunload` function ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950029/handle-refresh-page-event-with-javascript)), but it does not exactly solve the problem (I would say it has not the same behavior as user request).
- I would like to ignore the autoupdate case (like in `setInterval` or similar functions or scripts) from the manual update case. This question is about the manual one.
- The classical Android swipe-down update method for a web page is considered here as a manual update method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a user-generated update (before update) or just detect if the page was manually updated (after update)?

Comment: I don't think so, @Rapsssito . I am rather searching for a manual (a human being doing something) way.

Comment: Both methods would be OK, @F.Igor , as long as they are manually-generated, not started by a script or function. Added info to the original question to reflect.

Comment: Typically you code your links and anything that alters the page location to disable the onbeforeunload code that causes messages to pop up. There is really no way to deal with it or no what caused the page to unload.'

Answer (score -1):

My idea would be to use the sessionStorage to save the `window.location.href` on pageload. If the user reloads the page the stored location should match the current url:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  const lastUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('lastUrl');
  if(lastUrl && lastUrl === window.location.href) {
    alert("You requested update");
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem('lastUrl', window.location.href);
});
```

Comment: I am not sure, Mischa. My objective was rather to address the manual update case, not the autoupdate. It seems your could makes no differences about.

Comment: Ahh yes .... if u want to filter out automatic reloads you will need to intercept the automatic reloading events and delete the key first ... but i understand that this is not exactly what you asked for.